# xml parsing with children() doesn't work

Tags: php, xml-parsing

A XML-File has this structure:

```
<anbieter>
  <immobilie>
   <geo>
    <plz>0750</plz>
   </geo>
  </immobilie>
  <immobilie>
    <geo>
    <plz>0780</plz>
   </geo>
  </immobilie>
  ….
</anbieter>
```

I try to read this with the following code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($PATH_TO_XML);
foreach($xml -> anbieter -> children('immobilie') as $immobilie) {
  $ort = $immobilie -> geo;
  print $ort;
}
```

Unfortunately something is wrong, it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: try this:
$ort = $immobilie -> geo-> plz;

Comment: Thanks. i tried but it doesn't work eather. Is there something wrong on the foreach-bow?

Comment: is this is your complete xml file data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($PATH_TO_XML);
foreach($xml->immobilie as $immobilie) {
  $ort = $immobilie->geo->plz;
  echo $ort;
}
```

I have tried like:-

```
$str = '<anbieter>
  <immobilie>
   <geo>
    <plz>0750</plz>
   </geo>
  </immobilie>
  <immobilie>
    <geo>
    <plz>0780</plz>
   </geo>
  </immobilie>
</anbieter>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
foreach($xml->immobilie as $immobilie) {
  $ort = $immobilie->geo->plz;
  echo $ort; //07500780
}
```